# JS: Why do I have to click my canvas-resizing-button twice?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, image-resizing, double-click

I have an HTML5 canvas with the size of 392x392 in which I draw something.
I am trying to resize the content of that canvas into another canvas with the size of 28x28 pixels.

The following approach works fine, except that I have to click the "resize image" button twice - why is that and how can I fix it?

```js
function resize() {
  //get the base64 string of the Image
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  //draw the base64 string into a 28x28 canvas (for resizing)
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = dataURL;
  resizedCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 28, 28);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="392" height="392" style="border:1px solid;"></canvas>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="resize image" id="btn" size="30" onclick="resize()">
<br>
<br>
<canvas id="resizedCanvas" width="28" height="28" style="border:1px solid;"></canvas>

<script>
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  resizedCanvas = document.getElementById('resizedCanvas');
  resizedCtx = resizedCanvas.getContext('2d');
    
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 280, 280);
</script>
```

[code in jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/vhdk9s7x/13/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Important note:** do not even go through an img to resize your canvas. Simply draw the canvas directly over the resized one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Image` object not yet finished loading its content at the time you try to `drawImage`. You must wait until the image fires a `load` event. Before that event fires, the image will not render as anything, because it has not yet finished loading data from its `src` URL.

Your code works after a second click because the browser has cached the image data associated with that particular `src` after the first click, so it is ready to render immediately on the second click.

Simply place your `resizedCtx.drawImage(...)` call inside a callback function that will not run until chronologically after a `load` event fires for `img`.

```
function resize() {
  //get the base64 string of the Image
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  //draw the base64 string into a 28x28 canvas (for resizing)
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = dataURL;
  img.addEventListener("load", function() {
      resizedCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 28, 28);
  });
}
```

```js
function resize() {
//get the base64 string of the Image
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
//draw the base64 string into a 28x28 canvas (for resizing)
var img = new Image();
  img.src = dataURL;
  img.addEventListener("load", function() {
    resizedCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 28, 28);
  });
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="392" height="392" style="border:1px solid;"></canvas>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="resize image" id="btn" size="30" onclick="resize()">
<br><br>
<canvas id="resizedCanvas" width="28" height="28" style="border:1px solid;"></canvas>
<script>
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  resizedCanvas = document.getElementById('resizedCanvas');
  resizedCtx = resizedCanvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 280, 280);

</script>
```

Comment: Great answer! **+1** I hope you don't mind but I have added a Snippet to show your changes work as expected. I have it set to hide by default so it doesn't take up too much space and make your post look messy.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works fine!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your JS code with this

```
function resize() {
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('resizedCanvas');
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

Canvas will accept another canvas content. All you can do now is manipulate variable image to change it's positions and there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function resize() {
  //get the base64 string of the Image
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  //draw the base64 string into a 28x28 canvas (for resizing)
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    resizedCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 28, 28);
  };
  img.src = dataURL;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="392" height="392" style="border:1px solid;"></canvas>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="resize image" id="btn" size="30" onclick="resize()">
<br>
<br>
<canvas id="resizedCanvas" width="28" height="28" style="border:1px solid;"></canvas>

<script>
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  resizedCanvas = document.getElementById('resizedCanvas');
  resizedCtx = resizedCanvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 280, 280);
</script>
```

Just put the resizedCanvas and resizedCtx line inside the resize function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't change anything...

Comment: Hi! Answer updated.

Comment: Sorry, but I still have to click twice.

Comment: Don't know what had happened. It was happening on single click let me check. Sry

Answer (score 0):

you can use img.onload in other to load the image and then execute the funtion afterwards
     `function resize() {
      //get the base64 string of the Image
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
      //draw the base64 string into a 28x28 canvas (for resizing)
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = dataURL;
     img.onload = function () { 
        resizedCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 28, 28);
      }
     }`

just replace the input tag with the one here it will fix the problem.

```js
function resize() {
  //get the base64 string of the Image
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  //draw the base64 string into a 28x28 canvas (for resizing)
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = dataURL;
  img.onload = function () { 
  resizedCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 28, 28);
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="392" height="392" style="border:1px solid;"></canvas>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="resize image" id="btn" size="30" onclick="resize()">
<br>
<br>
<canvas id="resizedCanvas" width="28" height="28" style="border:1px solid;"></canvas>

<script>
 canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  resizedCanvas = document.getElementById('resizedCanvas');
  resizedCtx = resizedCanvas.getContext('2d');
    
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 280, 280);
</script>
```